# Serverless authorizer request does not provide methodArn, or any information about the calling lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I am having issues getting the `methodArn` from a request object in an authorizer lambda I have defined. I am using serverless with golang. Here is a redacted setup of the code that I have.

**main.go** - the authorizer handler function

```
func Handler(request events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequestTypeRequest) (events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse, error) {
  // I have tried logging the entire request to cloud watch, see further down for the sample

  // i have code here to verify a jwt token
  return nil, nil
}
```

**serverless.yml** - my serverless setup to register the function and define the authorizer

```
functions:
  permission_verify:
    handler: bin/handlers/permission/verify

package:
  patterns:
    - "!./**"
    - ./bin/**

provider:
  httpApi:
    authorizers:
      custom:
        functionName: permission_verify
        type: request
```

With the above setup I am able to use the authorizer in other microservices to verify `jwt` tokens but now I would like to add more functionality to the authorizer and with that I need the `methodArn` on the request to be present.

Here is the output from cloud watch after hitting an endpoint that uses the authorizer

**cloud watch** - the request json

```
{
    "type": "REQUEST",
    "methodArn": "",
    "resource": "",
    "path": "",
    "httpMethod": "",
    "headers": {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "authorization": "redacted",
        "content-length": "redacted",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "host": "redacted",
        "postman-token": "redacted",
        "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.31.3",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "redacted",
        "x-forwarded-for": "redacted",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
    },
    "queryStringParameters": null,
    "pathParameters": null,
    "stageVariables": null,
    "requestContext": {
        "path": "",
        "accountId": "redacted",
        "resourceId": "",
        "stage": "$default",
        "requestId": "redacted",
        "identity": {
            "apiKey": "",
            "sourceIp": ""
        },
        "resourcePath": "",
        "httpMethod": "",
        "apiId": "redacted"
    }
}
```

I have scoured the internet looking for an explanation and cause for having no information about the calling lambda in the request to no avail. It has been quite a bit of time, any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked using `REST` instead of `HTTP`. I had to redo all my functions and define the serverless like the following;

**serverless.yaml**

```
custom:
  authorizer:
    type: token
    identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
    identityValidationExpression: Bearer (.*)
    name: permission_verify
    # if this is in a different service, you can replace the name property with 'arn' having the arn of the function

functions:
  permission_verify:
    handler: bin/handlers/permission/verify

  permission_read:
    events:
      -http: # i had httpApi before
        method: get
        path: /
        authorizer: ${self:custom.authorizer}
```

This allowed me to change the function signature to something like below, and after checking the cloud watch logs, I was able to get the method ARN.

```
func Handler(request events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest) (events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse, error)
```

Here is an example of what I got in cloud watch;

```
{
    "type": "TOKEN",
    "authorizationToken": "Bearer <redacted>",
    "methodArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:redacted/PUT/"
}
```

In summary, the cause of this was just inconsistent serverless config that did not fit the purpose of what I required. I'd say IMO, it is easy to think that serverless is a fool proof way of defining infrastructure but it's not and it's good to understand what you're going for against what is offered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should be

```
func Handler(request events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest) (events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse, error) {
```

and not

```
func Handler(request events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequestTypeRequest) (events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse, error) {
```

See https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-golang-auth-examples/functions/auth/main.go for a working example

Comment: I tried this way, the ```methodArn``` is still blank, and the ```AuthorizationToken``` property is also empty.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's some kind of limitation on my AWS account, or even a permission that is not there.

Comment: ```{"type":"REQUEST","authorizationToken":"","methodArn":""} ```

Answer (score 0):

not sure how your serverless.yml file looks like, but this could be a good example in case.

```
service: your-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  httpApi:
    payload: '2.0'

functions:
  permission_verify:
    handler: bin/handlers/permission/verify
  your_protected_function:
    handler: bin/handlers/your_protected_function
    events:
      - httpApi:
          method: any # or the specific HTTP method you want to allow
          path: /your_path
          authorizer:
            name: custom

custom:
  authorizers:
    custom:
      functionName: permission_verify
      type: request

package:
  patterns:
    - "!./**"
    - ./bin/**
```

make sure that you are using the
events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest
type instead of
events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequestTypeRequest
for the request parameter in the Go code:

```
func Handler(request events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest) (events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse, error) {}
```

Comment: I tried this and it errored out while trying to deploy it.

Comment: I also tried reconfiguring the serverless.yml according to https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api#.